# Нужна ли запятая перед "или"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "или":

**Показания к применению: хромомикоз и мицетома, рефрактерные к итраконазолу, или при его непереносимости.**

Comment: Выглядит как неполное предложение. Для того, чтобы ответить на вопрос, желательно увидеть его в более широком контексте.

Comment: М_Г, вот, собственно, и весь контекст.

Comment: Эта фраза встречается в сети в описаниях лекарств - и с запятой, и без нее. С запятой: http://www.medicinform.net/spravka/n/n300.htm, 
http://lekargermany.ru/lekarstva/noksafil-100-mg, 
http://www.medikforum.ru/news/farma/5884-noksafil.html. Без запятой: https://www.webapteka.ru/drugbase/inn3372.html, 
http://provizor.org/node/13833, 
http://farmaspravka.com/pozakonazol-posaconazole, 
http://www.lsgeotar.ru/pozakonazol.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ответ исправлен:**

Запятая закрывает оборот, союз ИЛИ — разделительный.

**Показания к применению: хромомикоз и мицетома, *рефрактерные к итраконазолу*,  или при его (=итраконазола) непереносимости.**

Итраконазол — синтетическое противогрибковое средство широкого спектра действия.

РЕФРАКТЕРНЫЙ — (refractory) невосприимчивый.

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь ИЛИ соединяет два случая, при которых показано лекарство. Разделение предполагает альтернативу (ИЛИ-ИЛИ), а здесь вполне возможно совмещение обоих случаев.

Comment: *Полы в средневековом замке устилали ароматными травами или тростниковыми циновками.*(ЕГЭ) Объяснение: одиночный союз ИЛИ соединяет однородные члены предложения.

Comment: Так что, по-моему, вопрос стоит так: можно ли считать словосочетания "рефрактерные к итраконазолу" и "при его непереносимости" однородными членами предложения.

Comment: Союз всегда соединяет, существует союзная и бессоюзная связь. Но союзы  бывают соединительные, разделительные и т.д. Союз ИЛИ относится к разделительным. Можно посмотреть  http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=fda391e1-0b0e-408b-8a80-99fdd35b65d6

Comment: Сочинительные союзы могут связывать разнофункциональные члены предложения, которые  не являются однородными, например: Кто и в какой истребитель пустит Степу без сапог.

Comment: ИЛИ- только разделительный? А у Розенталя: "Следует различать пояснительный союз или (перед которым запятая ставится) и разделительный союз или (перед которым запятая не ставится, если союз не повторяется)". Но не доло не в названии, а в факте: ИЛИ может пояснять, соединять и разделять. С этим согласны?

Comment: Интуитивно согласен с отсутствием запятой, но хотелось бы увидеть четкую аргументацию, а ее у Вас не нашел, увы.

Comment: 1) Про значения союза ИЛИ я ещё в ответе говорила: у нас не пояснительное, не присоединительное, а разделительное. 2) Какую аргументацию вы хотите увидеть?  Мне такая грамматика не очень нравится, вряд ли она вообще нормативна, но что точно является нормой, так это отсутствие запятой при разделительном значении союза ИЛИ.

Comment: Я не вижу здесь разделительного значения (см, выше) , поэтому эта аргументация не подходит.

Comment: По определению, разделительные отношения предполагают выбор одного из вариантов, в нашем случае лекарство может для больного быть (1) неэффективным, (2) плохо переносимым. Верен только  один вариант: (1) больной принимает (переносит) лекарство, но оно не помогает ему;  (2) больной не принимает (не переносит) лекарство, тогда мы вообще ничего не можем сказать о его эффективности.

Comment: Возможно, вы правы: оборот надо закрыть, поэтому и запятая. Получается: хромомикоз и мицетома, рефрактерные к итраконазолу, или при ЕГО непереносимости (=непереносимости итраконазола). Тогда запятая очень даже на месте, только сложно понять, к чему относится местоимение "его". Но, наверное, это стандартная формулировка, поэтому должна пониматься.

Comment: Arinа, извините если я, что называется, морочу Вам голову. Но давайте разберемся. Смысл таков. Показания к применению: (1) хромомикоз и мицетома, рефрактерные к итраконазолу (2) хромомикоз и мицетома, при непереносимости итраконазола. Я писал, что интуитивно согласен с ОТСУТСТВИЕМ запятой, а Вы пишете: "Вы правы, оборот надо закрыть, поэтому и запятая"

Comment: Нет, мы, как мне кажется,  не поняли смысла сообщения (медицина всё-таки!), здесь вот что говорится:Показания к применению: 1) хромомикоз и мицетома, которые всегда являются рефрактерными к итраконазолу, или  (другие болезни) при  непереносимости больным итраконазола,  То есть рассматриваются случаи применения лекарства-заменителя, когда универсальный итраконазол применить нельзя. Если убрать /оборот, то запятая не будет ставиться, она относится именно к обороту, закрывая его.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед *или* не нужна.

См. все случаи (не)постановки запятой:

***[Когда перед союзом «или» ставится запятая?](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kogda-pered-soyuzom-ili-stavitsya-zapyataya.html)***

А также:

Разделительные союзы - **[5.1.1. Союз *или*](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#511)**

---

Подробный ответ на мой вопрос дан преподавателем русского языка с сорокалетним стажем, см. **[здесь](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1751684-zapjataja-pri-vstreche-li-l-ili-ili-soglasny-li-vy-so-slovarjom.html)**.